# Angular ui router (extras) $stateChangeStart event trigger twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

Can someone explain me why [Angular UI Router Extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) addition
trigger twice (on init!) `$stateChangeStart` event in case when i have some async ajax check and `e.preventDefault()` call?

**Short event code example:**

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
       console.log("$stateChangeStart");//fired twice
       if(!User.data) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
             .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log(data);
                  User.data = data; 
                  $state.go(toState, toParams);
              });
       }              
 });
```

[Full FIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLcxyxh1/)

Without extras addition everything is working as expected.

Tnx

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Then state change in success callback is never executed

Comment: triggers once, you prevent it because data hasn't returned....you redirect and it fires again. Would be much better to do this api call in resolve of the main app state

Comment: Please provide some fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs has multiple checks during its digest cycle to check before and after changes, this may be part of that cycle.

You can see this behavior during a $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('myVariable', function( change ){
  if( !change ){ return; }
  // do important things here.
});
```

During the first round of the digest **change** parameter will come in as **undefined**, until **myVariable** is set somewhere else. Once **myVariable** is set else-wear, the $watch will fire again and break through the if block to do some real work.

If this is the case with your function, perhaps you can add an **if** block and return if one or more of your parameters are undefined, or some value you do not with to execute on.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {

  if( !e || !toStateForExample || anotherParameter ){ return; }

  console.log("$stateChangeStart");//fired twice
  if(!User.data) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
      User.data = data; 
      $state.go(toState, toParams);
    });
   }              
 });
```

Comment: I think that must exist more elegant solution to fix this. That extras addition sometimes is really buggy

Comment: Try it out first, see if the thought is correct, then refactor to match your existing elegance.